# Installing applications from USB drive to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, software-installation

Currently I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic set up but no internet. So I can't install/download applications. What would be the easiest way to install applications de a USB drive onto Ubuntu?

Comment: Since you don't have internet, the best way would be packages which bundle all dependencies, like Flatpak or AppImage. Many apps offer Flatpak/AppImage versions.

Answer (score 0):

There are offline portable package manager, like this one

https://launchpad.net/cube-server

You can run it from a USB disk in the machine with Web access